# Number of ways I can partition a set of numbers into k segments without changing their order?

Tags: combinatorics

So I am aware of the Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind. However, for a given set such as $\{1,2,3,4\}$, it will create a subset such as $\{3,1\}$ if we wanted to partition into $k=2$ segments.

So how can I partition a set of length $l$ into $k$ segments given the conditions that we cannot have an empty set and that the values in the subset must be in the same order as in the original set.
So using an example with 4 elements, and I want to create 2 segments:

$\textbf{x}$ = $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$

Then I can have the following subsets if $k=2$ and combine any 2:

$\{x_1\}$ and $\{x_2,x_3,x_4\}$

$\{x_1, x_2\}$ and $\{x_3,x_4\}$

$\{x_1, x_3, x_3\}$ and $\{x_4\}$

I think that's correct and there are no more order dependent subsets.
Forgive me if any of my wording or terminologies have been incorrect. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the approach is known as *stars and bars*, but it's fairly easy to see that there will be $l-1$ places to drop a partition,  of which there are $k-1$...  So ${l-1}\choose  {k-1} $...

In your example $l=4$ and $k=2$, yielding  ${3\choose 1}=3$...